# Cannot use class from another directory into main java program

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to use a java class `hello` in my main program `test10`. `test10` is inside the folder "java" while class hello is in the folder "java1". Both these folders are at same level inside Documents folder. When I try to run the `test10` file using the command below (inside java folder):

```
java -cp ../java1/ test10
```

It gives `NoClassDefFoundError` of class hello (I've used ".." so that it goes one level up to find java1). I can't find the way to set the classpath so that I can run the program. Please help!

Comment: Both directories must be on your class path. Try `java -cp ../java1/:. test10` (if you're on Win, use `;` instead of `:`)

Comment: Thanxx, but when I do it like this: **java -cp .:../java1/ test10**, it is not working. Why??

Comment: The class path must include all directories with classes that you're **running** or **importing** in your classes. The command I suggested adds both directories to the class path, yours only adds one (`java1`). IOW, if you were to run this from the Documents directory, you'd have to type `java -cp java1:java test10` (all directories with your classes added to class path)